# android with cell size in android gridview

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview

Hi first sorry for what my English. 
I have an activity that contains a gridview (anything more). Want the same size as on all devices, but that's where I have a problem. 
In a galaxy s3 looks like I want, but testing it on a s2 are created rows.Mis spaces between rows contain images and text within the image.
s3 image
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwFa2jI8Xt2qcGNqajdsMVVSd2c/edit?usp=sharing
s2 image
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwFa2jI8Xt2qbmtmUERCRUVQNWs/edit?usp=sharing
CustomGridViewAdapter-

```
package com.proonet.camareroporfavor;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.proonet.camareroporfavor.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class CustomGridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ItemGridView> {
Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
ArrayList<ItemGridView> data = new ArrayList<ItemGridView>();

public CustomGridViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
        ArrayList<ItemGridView> data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    RecordHolder holder = null;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new RecordHolder();
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_text);
        holder.imageItem = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (RecordHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    ItemGridView item = data.get(position);
    holder.txtTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
    holder.imageItem.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());
    return row;

}

static class RecordHolder {
    TextView txtTitle;
    ImageView imageItem;

}
}
```

ItemGridview

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;


public class ItemGridView {
Bitmap image;
String title;

public ItemGridView(Bitmap image, String title) {
    super();
    this.image = image;
    this.title = title;
}
public Bitmap getImage() {
    return image;
}
public void setImage(Bitmap image) {
    this.image = image;
}
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}


}
```

My activity where I show the gridview

```
public class InicioActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private String[] opcionesMenu;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private ListView drawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
GridView gv;
ArrayList<ItemGridView> gridArray = new ArrayList<ItemGridView>();
CustomGridViewAdapter customGridAdapter;
private CharSequence tituloSeccion;  
private CharSequence tituloApp; 

TextView tVciudadDondeEstoy;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_inicio);

    tVciudadDondeEstoy = (TextView)  findViewById(R.id.ImageTextViewCiudadDondeEstoy);
    cambioEnTextViewSegunCiudad ();
    //Gridview
    //set grid view item
            Bitmap imagenVacia = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.cuadro_vacio);
            gridArray.add(new ItemGridView(imagenVacia,"Ofertas hoy"));

            gridArray.add(new ItemGridView(imagenVacia,"Locales adheridos"));

            gridArray.add(new ItemGridView(imagenVacia,"Mis Locales"));

            gridArray.add(new ItemGridView(imagenVacia,"Locales cercanos"));

            gridArray.add(new ItemGridView(imagenVacia,"Mis ofertas"));

            gridArray.add(new ItemGridView(imagenVacia,"Locales cercanos"));
            gridArray.add(new ItemGridView(imagenVacia,"algo"));
            gridArray.add(new ItemGridView(imagenVacia,"algo2"));
            gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
            customGridAdapter = new CustomGridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.row_grid, gridArray);
            gv.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);

    gv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(InicioActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() ;
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                break;
            case 1://boton ultimas ofertas,debe abrir la actividad ultimasOfertas de cada ciudad
                if (CrearPerfil.ciudadSeleccionada.equals( "Alicante" )){
                Intent intent = new Intent(InicioActivity.this, TipoDeLocalesActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                }else{
            Toast.makeText(InicioActivity.this, "No hay   ofertas para  tu localidad" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() ;}
                break;
            case 2:

                break;
            default:

            }
        }
    });
```

xml:Where I have the textview and imageview
row_grid

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/item_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:src="@drawable/cuadro_vacio" >
</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/item_image"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/item_image"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/item_image"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/item_image"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="¿Donde estoy?"
    android:textSize="20sp" 
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" 
    android:shadowColor="#c7c7c7"
    android:shadowDx="3" 
    android:shadowDy="2" 
    android:shadowRadius="1.8">
</TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My activity xml: activity_inicio.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- Contenido Principal -->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="#e3e3e3">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ibtnCiudad"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/cuadro_vacio525x450" />


   <!-- Texto que va dentro del imagebutton -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ImageTextViewCiudadDondeEstoy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ibtnCiudad"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ibtnCiudad"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ibtnCiudad"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:shadowColor="#c7c7c7"
        android:shadowDx="3"
        android:shadowDy="2"
        android:shadowRadius="1.8"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

 <GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ibtnCiudad"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="3dp"
    android:listSelector="#00000000"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="3dp" />
```

If anyone has the solution for the rows look at all dispositipos you tell me please. 
My intention is that it looks like the flippboard application. Row and text inside 
Thank you.

Comment: For if it helps someone. Here I found the best solution http://www.rogcg.com/blog/2013/11/01/gridview-with-auto-resized-images-on-android